# Extjs4 Chained combos

Tags: combobox, load, extjs4, store

I've a set of 2 combo boxes. One is countries combo and another is states combo. By default the states combo store is empty when I select a country then based on the combo value field States combo has to be filtered/load according to the first combo. In Extjs2.0 this is working whats the changes in Extjs4.

country store

```
var country_store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    //autoLoad: true,
    fields: ['id','c_id','c_name'],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'country_list.php',
        reader: {
           type:'json',
           root: 'results'
        }
    },
    storeId: 'edu_context_store'
});
```

State store

```
var state_name = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
autoLoad: true,
fields: ['id','s_id','s_name','parent_country_id'],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'states_list.php',
    reader: {
       type:'json',
       root: 'results'
    }
},
storeId: 'state_name'
```

});

Combo boxes

```
{
            xtype: 'combo',
            id: 'country_combo',
            hiddenName: 'country_name',
            displayField: 'c_name',
            valueField: 'c_id',
            fieldLabel: 'Country',
            queryMode: 'remote',
            allowBlank: false,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            store: country_store,
            width: 450,
            selectOnFocus: true,
            listeners:{
            scope: this,
            'select': function(combo, rec, idx){
               var country_val = combo.getRawValue();
               var states_obj = Ext.getCmp('states_combo');        
                        states_obj.clearValue();
                        //states_obj.store.load();
                        states_obj.store.filter('parent_country_id', country_val);


            }                           
        }

        }, {
            xtype: 'combo',
            id: 'states_combo',
            hiddenName:'state_name',
            displayField:'s_name',
            valueField:'s_id',
            queryMode: 'remote',
            fieldLabel: 'State',
            cls: 'textlineht',
            allowBlank: false,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            store: states_store,
            width: 450

        }
```

Anyone knows how to do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: why is this commented out ?  //states_obj.store.load();

Comment: I had define autoLoad:true property in states store.

Comment: ^ so it loads once when it's rendered and then never more

Comment: Thats fine. I'm facing issue with store filtering. states_obj.store.filter('parent_country_id', country_val); is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combo.getRawValue()` will return the value displayed to the user in the combo - not the underlying id value. Try instead `combo.getValue()`.

Comment: Thanks Amalea.By using combo.getValue(). I can able to get valueField but the states combo is not filtering.

Comment: I'm getting counties and states json data.Like this   //Country store ({"total":"2","results":[{"id":"1","c_id":"US","c_name":"United Kingdom"},{"id":"2","c_id":"UK","c_name":"United States",}]})     //States store   ({"total":"2","results":[{"id":"7","s_id":"nyk","s_name":"New york","parent_country_id":"US"},{"id":"8","s_id":"lon","s_name":"Landon","parent_country_id":"UK"}]})

Comment: From the documentation the listener should be setup like this: `listeners: { select: { fn: function(){  }, scope: this } }`, I'd try re-writing it with this syntax and see if that helps.