# how to use filter in ExtJs store?

Tags: extjs

I created a store using ExtJs and i want to load the value of store to ComboBox. But before loading values i need to filter some data based on value selected in another comboBox.

So for that purpose i think i need to apply  filter on store, please any body can help me how i can do that.

Model:-

```
Ext.define('City', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
fields: [
        { name: 'StateId', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'City', type: 'string' },
]});
```

Store:-

```
var cityStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
model: 'City',
data : [
    { StateId: '1', City: 'Bangalore'},
    { StateId: '1', City: 'Mysore'},
    { StateId: '1', City: 'Dharwad'},
    { StateId: '2', City: 'Mumbai'},
    { StateId: '2', City: 'Pune'},
    { StateId: '2', City: 'Nagpur'}
   ]});
```

Now i am using this **cityStore** to load in Combobox. but before load i want if **stateId is 1** then only 3 records **(Bangalore, Mysore, Dharwad)** are load in combobox and if **stateId is 2** then other 3 records are load in combobox. How i can achive it.

Comment: You may check this : It has a good small tutorial along with a working sample at JSFiddle. 
http://atechiediary.blogspot.com/2013/06/extjs-how-to-filter-data-of-store-in.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

According to [Ext.data.Store filter](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-filter) method documentation:

```
var stateId = 1; // your value
cityStore.clearFilter(true);
cityStore.filter('StateId', stateId);
```

**Update**

I've found that ComboBox filters data by itself and there is no opportunity to change it's behaviour. But I see two solutions of this problem:

1. Filter data manually (see [Ext.util.MixedCollection filter](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.util.MixedCollection-method-filter)) and load it into your store (see [Ext.data.Store load](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-load))
2. Disable store's `clearFilter` and `filter` methods and use own `cityFilter`:

   ```
   Ext.define('CityStore', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
       filter: Ext.emptyFn,
       clearFilter: Ext.emptyFn,
       cityFilter: function (stateId) {
           Ext.data.Store.prototype.clearFilter.call(this);
           Ext.data.Store.prototype.filter.call(this, 'StateId', stateId);
       }
   });
   ```

   Then use `cityFilter()` method.

Comment: what ExtJs version do you use?

Comment: I am using Ext JS 4.1.1 and I can directly set `filterBy` on the data store without overwriting `clearFilter` and `filterBy`/`filter`. Though I have set `queryMode: 'local'` on the combobox.

Comment: @AlexeySolonets how to implement multicolumn local filter

Comment: There are hundreds of examples of this on the sencha forum and on Stack - just google 'grouped combo field extjs4'

Similar Question asked here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323284/extjs4-chained-combos